# PouchDB/Javascript - Edit mode sends values into wrong field

Tags: javascript, html, css, pouchdb

I've set up an admin page to add items to the database via PouchDB, but when I go into edit mode and save the changes, the value of the "year" field goes into the "title field". Could someone take a look at the code and let me know where I'm going wrong please?

It wont work on the SO editor so heres a codepen...

https://codepen.io/ZeeBiz/pen/KJPPvK

```
<p> help me please</p>
```

To see what I mean, add a new review, pick a title and a year, then click on edit and save the changes, the year will replace the title

Answer (score 0):

I found a duplicate! Solved it!

```
thisFilm.title = document.getElementById('title').value;
thisFilm.title = document.getElementById('year').value;
```